# How many supervisors do I need for an Erlang app?

Tags: nginx, erlang, erlang-supervisor

I want to create a webapp with the microservices approach in mind.

It will consist of a set of independent services made as Erlang applications, that I will be able to start and stop separately. In front of them there will be nginx server working as a reverse proxy.

Should I put all these services under one god supervisor or should I keep them separate having a supervisor for each?

Based on what facts should I make this decision?

Answer (score 0):

By making each service an Erlang application, you already have the answer: each application has a separate supervision tree.

Answer (score 0):

In my mind the answer depends on the ability (or necessity) to release your apps in run independently.

If the services need to stay consistent due to interfaces that are likely to change, it will be easier to have one, or a limited number, of supervision tree (and application(s). The start and stop of services is then an interface of your application(s).

If your services are independent, or if they have very stable interfaces (using a standard for example), or if you don't care about releasing in run, then an application per service seems to be a preferred solution.

Answer (score 0):

Supervisors are there with well defined goal in mind: to give you control over the way your state is managed in presence of errors.

If you have two parts (A and B) of application. Each stores some state: SA and SB. You can decide how to construct your supervision tree basing on one question: does this part of state make sense without other part of state? Can my app continue to work correctly if A is restarted and SA is cleared but B is not restarted and SB is not cleared?

When looking at supervisor, people often think about restarts and rate of restarts. Arguably, this is less important part of supervisor. What you should really care is what is started and in which order. What should be restarted and in which order?

Supervisor gives three strategies for restarts.

- one_for_one - this assumes that states of managed children are independent. Default and least useful of all of them.
- one_for_all - if one of children dies, state of other children have to be cleared as well
- rest_for_one - children on the left should not be restarted, children on the right should be restarted.

Other concept that I really like is ["error kernel"](http://jlouisramblings.blogspot.com/2010/11/on-erlang-state-and-crashes.html). In case of rest_for_one children on the left are your "error kernel".

One more important thing you have to know is that supervisor starts all children in order left-to-right, depth-first. And stops them in reverse order.